# How a surjective group homomorphism induces chain map on complexes?

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I have following confusion while reading a statement:

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups and $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ be a surjective homomorphism. Let $B(G)$ and $B(Q)$ denote the bar resolutions of $G$ and $Q$ over the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\phi$ gives rise to surjective chain maps (of chain complexes) $\phi_{\#}: B(G) \bigotimes_{G} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow B(Q) \bigotimes_{Q} \mathbb{Z}  $.

What are $\phi_{\#}$?